# I want to check if the first letter of user first input is similar to the first letter for second user input

Tags: java, netbeans-7

The program will prompt user to enter his name then enter different names
Then it will check if the first letter of these dofferent names is similar to the first letter of his name

I tried

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) 
String MyName;
MyName = input.nextLine();
String FreindName;
FreindName = input.nextLine();
int count

char let1 = FreindName.CharAt(0);

char let2 = MyName.CharAt(0);

if (let1 == let2){

        count++;}
```

The problem is after processing the program the count is still 0

Comment: First, that's not going to compile, but, what exactly is you input?

Comment: I want first to enter a name then in a loop i will enter several names

Comment: Yes, but in what ways does your current work flow not work - because I have to say, once I correct the code to compile, it works fine

Comment: The program should calculate the percentage of the names that starts with the same letter of his owm name

Comment: The percentage is still 0 after running the program

Comment: Ok, you need to stop for a second.  You've dumped a out-of-context code snippet, which doesn't compile, on us and then started adding requirements not originally stated in your question, so frankly, it's going to be impossible for use to provide you with any useful direction.  Consider updating your question, outlining your goal(s), your expected and actual results and a [mcve]